# Image of the natural embedding of a normed linear space

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Let $X=C[0,1]$ with the norm $\|x\|_1=\int_0^1 |x(t)|\,dt$, $x\in C[0,1]$ and $\Omega=\left\{f\in X':\|f\|=1\right\}$, where $X'$ denotes the dual space of $X$. Let $C(\Omega)$ be the linear space of continuous functions on $\Omega$ with the norm $\|u\|=\sup_{s\in\Omega}|u(s)|$, $u\in C(\Omega)$. Let $\Phi:X\rightarrow C(\Omega)$ be the natural linear isometry defined by $\Phi_x(f)=f(x)$ for $f\in\Omega$ and $x\in X$.

**Problem:** Show that $\Phi:X\rightarrow C\left(\Omega\right)$ is not onto.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Is it really a norm? $\Omega$ is not compact since $X'$ is of infinite dimension so continuous functions might not need to be bounded. But anyway, once that problem is solved, here's a hint: remember that your space $X$ is not complete, while $C_b(\Omega, \mathbb{K})$ the space of bounded continuous functions from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{K}$ ($K = \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, you didn't specify) is complete for the norm provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f\in \Omega$ then $(-f)\in\Omega$.
We have
$$\Phi_x(-f)=-\Phi_x(f)\ \forall\, x\in X, f\in\Omega.\quad (*)$$
Let $x_0\in X$ such that $x_0\neq0$. Then
$$\Phi_{x_0}(-f_0)\neq0\neq \Phi_{x_0}(f_0)$$
for some $f_0\in\Omega$.
Define $\psi:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ by the formula
$$\psi(f)=\big(\Phi_{x_0}(f)\big)^2.$$
Function $\psi$ is continuous as a composition of continuous maps, i.e. $\psi\in C(\Omega)$. But $\psi$ does not satisfy $(*)$:
$$\psi(f_0)=\big(\Phi_{x_0}(f_0)\big)^2=\big(\Phi_{x_0}(-f_0)\big)^2=\psi(-f_0)$$
So, $\psi\notin \Phi(X)$.
In the last chain of equalities, it is important that $\psi(f_0)≠0$.